# How do I carry the last octet of the IPv4-address to the part changed by sed?

Tags: sed

I am going to upgrade my network from 64 to 128 IPs. Of course I don't want to change it manually on all 40+ VMs. I plan to use an ansible ad-hoc command with sed -i and then use the same to restart the interfaces. I have tried but and I have found - thank you guys - a solution how to replace the slash in the address, but I still need  to carry the last octet of the IP address as a variable into the output. This here works but only partially

Original Text:

```
address 195.23.154.X/26
```

What I want:

```
 address 195.34.154.X/25
```

in `/etc/network/interfaces/`

My partially-working sed command with escaped slashes:

```
 sed 's/address\ 195.24.153.3\/26/address\ 195.23.154.4\/27/g' interfaces.bak
```

How do I keep the '3' in this example?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace all slashes that are part of the `sed` command syntax with a different charcter and keep the slashes that are part of your pattern or replacement, e.g.

```
sed 's#foo/bar#foo/baz#'
```

Another option is to escape all slashes that are part of your strings

```
sed 's/foo\/bar/foo\/baz/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually *need* to match the string `address` explicitly, followed by the first three parts of the IP address literally, and then update the subnet mask from `/26` to `/25`:

```bsh
sed 's|\(address 195\.23\.154\.[0-9]*\)/26|\1/25|'
```

I'm, first of all, using `|` as a delimiter for the `s///` command.  I do this to avoid having to escape the slashes.  Any single character can be used as the delimiter in the substitution command (apart from a small number of obvious ones, like newline).

I then capture the first part of the string that matches up to the slash in the address, using `\(...\)` (note that I need to escape the dots in the expression to be able to match only literal dots in those locations).  I'm then able to insert this using a back-reference, `\1`, in the replacement part of the command.

Since I also captured the last part of the IP address, naively matched by `[0-9]*`, this will be carried over unchanged to the replacement.

Testing:

```bsh
$ echo 'address 195.23.154.112/26' | sed 's|\(address 195\.23\.154\.[0-9]*\)/26|\1/25|'
address 195.23.154.112/25
```